# How can use a data from angular in blade form?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I need use angulaar data like parameter in a Blade form, but i don´t know how to do it

This is my code
Sorry for my English

```
                <tr ng-repeat="data in datos">
              <td>{{data.PAGO}}</td>
              <td>{{data.AUTORIZACION}}</td>
              <td>{{data.FECHAYHORA}}</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li>{!! Form::open(['route'=>array('movimientosC.destroy',//I need angular data here//),'method'=>'DELETE']) !!}
                        <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="1"><div class="container">{!!Form::submit('Cancelar',['class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-xs']);!!}
                      </div>{!! Form::close() !!}</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either change angular brackets through use of $interpolateProvider:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

Or you can change laravel blade tags:

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in blade by using the syntax `@{{ data.PAGO }}`.  The `@` tells blade it should render that as text.

Comment: If what I said was false or if I've misinterpreted the question, please leave a comment.

Comment: While you're correct, it seems @Jasiel is trying to get data from Angular and pass it to Laravel's `route()` method. I don't think that warrants downvotes, though.